# How was Shoto Todoroki able to resist One for All?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Something that I dont understand from My Hero Academia it's something characters which supposedly have average resistance (because their quirks arent about resistance) are able to resist One for All. For example, Shoto in it's battle with Midoriya (and wasnt this One for All 100%?) How was Shoto Todoroki able to resist One for All?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is basically given in chapter 22 of the manga. When Midoria tells All Might that he managed to hit Nomu without breaking his arm, they come to the conclusion that Midoria subconsciously limited his power output to avoid causing lethal harm to other humans. Mostly possible, that during his fight with Todoroki, he has limited his power in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The power level of that punch or others are not specifically stated in the manga or somewhere else.

- We know that Izuku's current limit of %20. More than that harms him. This is also valid if he is using Full Cowl.
- In many fights Izuku exaggerates the power output of his quirk. Muscular fight is the best example for this. He never uses %100 output nor that he can stand that kind of harm.

So since he is not using Full Cowl here we can assume his power output is noting more than %10. Because his power output is only %5-6 without Full Cowl.

Comment: hmmm I thought that everytime he was hurting himself it was because he was using 100%, before he learnt how to use 5% only.

Comment: One for All materialises in a different way for every user. For All Might it changes his body. For Izuku it changes the colour of his vein. Also there is that greenish lightning effect when he uses Full Cowl. We cant know when he will able to use %100 since Izuku will not enhance his body when it happens but for now we are far from it.

Comment: Please take into account that tournament was happening prior to internship, therefore Mydoria was unable to use Full Cowl (neither 5% nor 20%) at that time.

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that because Endeavor has pushed todoroki so far, that todoroki learned to cope with painful attacks. Or Midoriya wasn’t using 100%.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! We appreciate your contribution, but pure opinion/speculation answer is discouraged. Instead, please [edit] and try to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its either Midoriya wasn't using 100% OR Endeavor pushed Todoroki so far that he could resist painful attacks, that's all I think lmao

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! We appreciate your contribution, but pure opinion/speculation answer is discouraged. Instead, please [edit] and try to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple answers like endevor training shoto through painful ways so now shoto is immune to some painful attacks and that we probly know that deku can roughly control the power he uses on someone so as he did not want to severely injure shoto he used 1 or 3 something percent i think both.

Comment: Hi @AditeyaSharma, welcome to Anime & Manga SE. Do go through our [tour]! We discourage purely speculative answers here, so please try and [edit] your answer to include relevant sources or citations to support your statements. Thanks!